# The data type is not displayed. Inlay Hints

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea

DataType only appears in long codes. How do I solve this problem?

[image]

Inlay Hints | Kotlin | Types -> Show hints for property types. Active. Help pls!

Comment: You can enable type hints in Preferences | Editor | Inlay Hints | Kotlin | Types -> Show Hints For: Local Variable types.

Does it help?

Comment: It's already active.